# How to mock static variable/property in phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I want write a test for php function using phpunit.

I have a class named `Member`:

```
class Member {
    public static STATUS_DELETED = 'deleted';
    public static STATUS_NORMAL = 'normal';

    private $name;
    private $status;

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name();
    }

    public function getStatus() {
        return $this->status;
    }
}
```

A class `MemberService`, it is target to be tested:

```
class MemberService() {
    public function printMember(Member $member) {
        // Maybe some other logic, it's just a sample

        $status = $member->getStatus();

        // this line will get error when run test!
        if ($status == ‘Member::STATUS_DELETED’) {
            echo "this member " . $member->getName() . " has deleted";
        } else {
            echo $member->getName();
        }
    }
}
```

And a phpunit test case:

```
class MemberServiceTest extends MyUnitTestCase {
    protected function setUp() {
    }

    protected function tearDown() {
    }

    public testPrintMember() {
        $memberService = new MemberService();

        // mock member
        $member = $this->createMock(Member::class);

        $member->method('getName')
            ->willReturn('zhangsan');

        $member->method('getStatus')
            // can not use Member::STATUS_NORMAL in there after mock
            ->willReturn('normal');

        $MemberService->printMember($member);

        // assert some thing in there
    }
}
```

Then i run the test, get error: `Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'STATUS_DELETED' in ...`

`Member::STATUS_DELETED` it's just a const variable, it also can put in some otherwhere, but i don't want to move it.

How can i mock static variable/property?

Comment: `‘Member::STATUS_DELETED’` why this code have a quotation? I don't think it needs a quotation since this is constant variable.

Comment: make it `const STATUS_DELETED = 'deleted';` so you can access it as a constant like `Member::STATUS_DELETED`. Right now it is declared as a static variable (btw it should be then `$STATUS_DELETED`)